# How to write Parquet files with Pandas that can be read in AWS Athena?

Tags: pandas, parquet, amazon-athena

I have a simple dataframe that I would like to convert to a Parquet file:

```
out_buffer = BytesIO()
input_datafame.to_parquet(out_buffer, index=False, compression="gzip")
```

When I do this the resulting Parquet file has the following:

```
file schema:               schema
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
somID: OPTIONAL INT64 R:0 D:1
SessionID:                 OPTIONAL INT64 R:0 D:1
JobID:                     OPTIONAL INT64 R:0 D:1
JobCreationTime:           OPTIONAL BINARY L:STRING R:0 D:1
ProcessedId:               OPTIONAL BINARY L:STRING R:0 D:1
S3Results:                 OPTIONAL BINARY L:STRING R:0 D:1
```

Table create:

```
  `someid` bigint COMMENT '', 
  `sessionid` bigint COMMENT '', 
  `jobid` bigint COMMENT '', 
  `jobcreationtime` string COMMENT '', 
  `processedid` string COMMENT '', 
  `s3results` string COMMENT ''
```

Querying the data results in the following:

```
HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR: com.amazonaws.services.datacatalog.model.InvalidInputException: Error: 
type expected at the position 0 of 'integer' but 'integer' is found. 
(Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null; Proxy: null)
```

I suspect two issues causing this:

- incompatible integer types
- optional types

Is this a well known issue that I am not aware of? I could not find any details about this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a difference between integer and int in Athena. Int works, integer does not. Not sure why. The Parquet file is fine with optional fields.